# Jersey SSL exception on connect to WSO2

Tags: java, rest, ssl, jersey, wso2

I'm developing Jersey web service. In one of the methods, I'm invoking WSO2 Identity Server API: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#mePost

When I try to invoke it howerver, it returns following exception:

```
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The code I'm using:

```
Client restClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = restClient.target("https://localhost:9443/api/identity/user/v0.9/me");

String username = "admin";
String separator = ":";
String password = "admin";
// String passphrase = "";

HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(username, password);

restClient.register(feature);

Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeAsString(username + ":" + password));
Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(UserBean.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

So where is the problem. I thought that my authentication failed, the log from WSO2 would support it, because it states:

```
Error occurred while trying to authenticate and  Authorization header values are not define correctly.
```

So I checked the header in the variables of debuger and it is set correctly, all is according to documentation. I also found this question:

[Java Certificate Client SSL: unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192796/java-certificate-client-ssl-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requeste)

Which states, that my client doesn't trust the server certificate and that I should import it. Ok, but, i'm not using any keystore on level of Java or Jersey, where would I put such keystore? Also to note, the Identity Server runs locally uned localhost certificate. When I try to connect from browser, it wanrs me from enetering the site, presumably because client (browser) doesn't trust the certificate as it is self-signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was, to export the certificate from local WSO2 IS server. You than have 2 options, you can

- either [add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617210/how-to-properly-import-a-selfsigned-certificate-into-java-keystore-that-is-avail) it to cacerts in JAVA_HOME
- or create explicit catalina [truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833732/configure-truststore-in-tomcat) and import the certificate into those.